# How can I group it by using "search" function in regular expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I have been developing a python web-crawler to collect the used car stock data from this website. (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I&page=20)

First of all, I would like to collect only "BMW" from the list. So, I used "search" function in regular expression like the code below. But, it keeps returning "None".

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Please give me some advice.

Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

CAR_PAGE_TEMPLATE = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I&page="

def fetch_post_list():

    for i in range(20,21):
        URL = CAR_PAGE_TEMPLATE + str(i)
        res = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
        html = res.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table', class_='cyber')
        print ("Page#", i)

        # 50 lists per each page
        lists=table.find_all('tr', itemtype="http://schema.org/Article")

        count=0
        r=re.compile("[BMW]")
        for lst in lists:
            if lst.find_all('td')[3].find('em').text:
                lst_price=lst.find_all('td')[3].find('em').text
                lst_title=lst.find_all('td')[1].find('a').text
                lst_link = lst.find_all('td')[1].find('a')['href']
                lst_photo_url=''
                if lst.find_all('td')[0].find('img'):
                    lst_photo_url = lst.find_all('td')[0].find('img')['src']
                count+=1
            else: continue

            print('#',count, lst_title, r.search("lst_title"))

    return lst_link

fetch_post_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r.search("lst_title")
```

This is searching inside the string literal `"lst_title"`, not the variable named `lst_title`, that's why it never matches.

```
r=re.compile("[BMW]")
```

The square brackets indicate that you're looking for one of those characters. So, for example, any string containing `M` will match. You just want `"BMW"`. In fact you don't even need regular expressions, you can just test:

```
"BMW" in lst_title
```

Comment: Thnks for the comment. I appreciate it Alex.